# What are good use of alliterative words for describing a rain on the tin roof?

Tags: british-english, alliteration

I just had this question in my school homework asking to use alliteration words. The question was like this:

Use words with the same beginning to describe the sounds made by the words in bold:

A) Rain on the tin roof: It _______________ and ___________________ and __________________ and ____________________ and ___________________

Could anyone please reply to this and help out on which words could fit in that sentence? Thanks a lot!

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/205634/what-is-a-good-verb-to-describe-the-pleasant-sound-of-rain

Comment: Hope this helps!

Comment: "Pitter-patter" is probably the most familiar term, unless it's raining hard, in which case "drumming" or some such would likely be used.

Comment: have you looked for synonyms/near synonyms of the verb  'rain' in a thesaurus? Collocates of the noun 'rain' in a dictionary of collocations?

Answer (score 1):

The question is a rather contrived test of vocabulary recall.

One answer might be that the rain splashed and splattered and spilled and sprayed and sprinkled.

No doubt there are other alliterative possibilities. Dropped, drizzled, drenched, drained and dribbled come to mind.